# How to remove Start of field space in mysql?

Tags: mysql

The name field in the front, into the data will be added space (PS, in front of a few data is artificially modified). Such influence behind the search. I use the insert statement is:

insert into user(name,password,email,create_time) VALUES(' $name','$password','$email','$time')"

The fields of the name format is VARCHAR (45). There are two kinds of ending online, first is to use str_replace functions remove spaces and special characters of PHP, and then will add spaces.
The second is to use the MySQL statement trim, still can add spaces.
Then I direct to replace a $name string, or found space.
So I think should be MySQL internal affairs, tracking here not to proceed. Hope someone can answer.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a field of type VARCHAR in front of name, after can be deleted.